# DNS Zone file will not load

Tags: bind

Using BIND, I need to determine why my newly created zone file fails the named-checkzone check. Here in order is the named.conf file, the zone file and the error. I have tried changing the ip not sure what the problem is

```
logging {
channel default_debug {
file "data/named.run";
severity dynamic;
print-severity yes;
};
};
zone "example.vm." {
type master;
file "db.example";
allow-update { none; };
};
zone "." IN {
type hint;
file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";

[root@office1 named]# cat db.example
$TTL 3H
$ORIGIN example.vm.
example.vm. IN SOA office1.example.vm. root.example.vm. (
1 ; serial
1D ; refresh
1H ; retry
1W ; expire
3H ) ; minimum
example.vm NS office1.example.vm.
office1 A 10.73.111.72

[root@office1 named]# named-checkzone example.vm db.example
zone example.vm/IN: has no NS records
zone example.vm/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

Comment: Does the zone file have nameserver (`NS`) records?

Comment: these right?      example.vm. NS server1.example.vm.

server1  A 192.168.56.106

Comment: `named-checkconf` and `named-checkzone` are your friends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `db.example` zone file probably has a typo on the line

```
example.vm NS office1.example.vm.
```

This will get interpreted relative to the origin, becoming `example.vm.example.vm.`

Make sure to add a dot at the end or in this case use the character `@` which denotes the origin. Either of the following should work

```
example.vm. NS office1.example.vm.
@ NS office1.example.vm.
```

Comment: example.vm. NS office1.example.vm.worked!  Great eye.  Thank you

Comment: @colonutspanics If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment to [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on [the checkmark on the left](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/203101). That will mark the question as answered and is the way that thanks are conveyed on the Stack Exchange sites.